# Where to store solutions .sln file in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I read few things regarding this issue but I'm still a bit confused so I will try to present my scenario and questions.

First of all I read that you shouldn't store your .sln file in the same folder as .csproj. The reason for this is that when you will try to add a new project it will be added above the directory with .sln file.

This is from Visual studio 2010 best practices: [[Link]](http://books.google.pl/books?id=UJ-iJn56du4C&pg=PA155&lpg=PA155&dq=visual%20studio%20sln%20in%20the%20same%20place%20as%20csproj&source=bl&ots=GwJe4_S9lI&sig=3Rm2OKS0dKpLF6d90AUkRTiF8H8&hl=pl&sa=X&ei=Fq5TVIuxAZLYasPRgYAK&sqi=2&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=visual%20studio%20sln%20in%20the%20same%20place%20as%20csproj&f=false)

Now I'm using VS 2013 so is this any different ? Because when I create a new project its root folder is placed exactly where the .sln file is.This is for all the projects created using New project... in Visual studio and later using Add new project.. clicking on solution in Visual Studio.

The reason I ask this is because I copied a project using this step by step [[Link]](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4e169260-79f4-48d8-9d12-e7bbb96dfc18/create-new-c-project-similar-to-an-existing-c-project?forum=csharpgeneral)

and everything is working great except the part with the .sln placing. To copy the project I delete the .sln of the first project and let visual studio create a new one. By default Visual studio tries to do that in the same directory as .csproj. So I go one directory above and place the .sln there. The problem is with adding a new project. It actually starts to behave as in the example from Visual Studio best practices book (creates new project one directory above).

I hope all of this is not too confusing. If so I can elaborate.

This is a very important topic since I will be doing this fairly often(copying projects) and I need this to work exactly as it should.

Cheers!

Comment: I'm using VS2013 as well, and haven't seen what you describe. If I create a new project with a new solution, I get a folder with an .sln inside and folder for the project. Inside that folder is the .csproj file. Then, if I add another project to this solution, again, I get a new folder at the level of the .sln, with the .csproj inside that folder.

Comment: It's an option. There is a checkbox in the create new project dialog called "create directory for solution" if you tick it then it creates the project in a subfolder of the solution folder, if you don't it creates them in the same folder.

Comment: @BenRobinson Yes this is what I'm going for. I just created two test projects and I see the difference. So I guess my question is how can I ,,tick it on" for my copied project ? Because when I remove my .sln in the copied project and I create run Visual Studio asks me where to place the new .sln but doesn't ask me how should it create new projects later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new project (File-->New-->Project) there is a check box `Create directory for solution`.  Ensure that is checked to create a folder for your solution and a sub-folder for your project.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a new project from scratch, you'll see how Visual Studio creates a project / solution by default:

- Solution Folder

  - Solution.sln
  - Project1 Folder

    - Project1.csproj
  - Project2 Folder

    - Project2.csproj
  - etc